# RegEx to allow at least one dot and all character

Tags: regex, validation, email, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How do I validate the following emails with a regular expression?

#### Input

```
nagarjuna.nag@vm.com
nagarjuna12.nag@vm.com
nagarjuna12.nag.some@vm.com
```

#### Attempt

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)$/
```

Comment: I have tried using pattern /^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)$/ .But it is not working

Comment: if your requirement is to validate email addresses using regex, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that here we wish to validate these emails, for which we can use an expression similar to:

```
^([a-z0-9]+((?=\..+@.+\..+)[a-z0-9.]*@[a-z0-9]*\.[a-z0-9]*))$
```

with an `i` flag and we can allow more chars, if we like so.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ikQiP/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]